# Forces from momentum flux in pipe bend Confusion

Tags: fluid-mechanics

[image]

I understand the general process of solving these kind of problems. First draw the control volume and then show the forces on the boundaries and draw the reactions. In this case, there will be sum of forces in the x-direction and y-direction. I have obtained a solution from instructor which has a part that I am unsure of.

Here is the solution:

[image]

Can someone pelase explain why $u_1$ which is the velocity is $0$ in the y-direction and why  $u_2$ is $0$ in the x-direction? How do get this part?

Answer (score 2):

When the fluid is moving horizontally, it is assumed that there is no movement in the Y direction up to the point it gets to the bend.

The same argument is made for the flow in the vertical Y direction that there is no movement in the X direction.

Even with turbulent flow, this assumption is made.

Comment: Hi solar Mike, thanks for the help again! Just before I accept the answer, so $U_1$ is the initial velocity and it is travelling in a horizontal direction?